# changing stylesheet in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two actionlinks on my MVC view like this:

```
   <%= Html.ActionLink
      ("click me","Partial1","Temp",new { s = "0" },new { id = "mylink" }) %>

    <%= Html.ActionLink
      ("click me second link","Partial1", "Temp", null, 
      new { id = "mysecondlink" }) %>
```

and I have four style for these two links. if mylink is slected i want to apply #mylinkselected style to it  and #mysecondlinknoselected to mysecondlink and if mysecondlink is selected, I want to apply #mysecondlinkselected to it and #mylinknotselected to mylink

I can not change the ids as I have code related to these links at top of view

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#mylink').click(function() {
                $('#resultpartial1').load(this.href);
                return false;
            });
        });

        $(function() {
            $('#mysecondlink').click(function() {
            $('#resultpartial1').load(this.href, { s: "1"  });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

how to change styles ?

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to just set an `A:active` style for the links.  This will apply that style to whichever link is clicked.

http://www.echoecho.com/csslinks.htm

Comment: how to apply it on html.actionlink

Comment: Just define the `A:active` style in your CSS, and then apply that CSS class in your link.